# CSP hash values for external files which change - hash no longer valid

Tags: font-awesome, content-security-policy

I have recently been tightening up the content security policies for one of my sites. This site uses font awesome for its icons.

As part of this, I've included `https://*.fontawesome.com/` under several parts of my csp rule, including: script-src, font-src, etc.

These then load other .js files, which as I don't want to include unsafe-line in my csp rule, I have to include several hash values within my csp rule, one for each of these .js files.

This was working well until recently, when it appears that font awesome updated these .js files, such that the hash values I was using were no longer valid.

I was able to update my code with the new hash values, after I noticed this. However, the icons on my site were not displaying for an unknown length of time whilst the hash values were invalid, which isn't great.

Is there anyway of checking whether the hash values are still valid for these files, and if they are not, being notified? Or do I just need to check my site manually on a regular basis?

Or do you a different approach to avoid this issue?